# Maclaurin series for $\sin^{-1 }z$ for a specific determination

Tags: complex-analysis

Choose a specific determination , find Maclaurin expansions for $\sin^{-1}z$ ,

and state the region for which the expansion is valid .
$$\sin^{-1} z=-i(\operatorname{Log} \ iz + \sqrt{1-z^2)}$$

Then I calculated the series $$\sin^{-1}z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n)!^2} \frac{z^{2n+1}}{2n+1} $$

My Question is What is meant by "Choose a specific determination"?

Thank you...

Comment: Just a little comment about notation: I think it is more precise to write $\arcsin$ instead of $\sin^{-1}$ because the last form can be interpreted in many different ways, and it seems that the sine function have an inverse, what is not really true.

Comment: A **determination** of a function refers historically to functions that could be multivalued (for example, in former times, you were meeting definitions where arctan was sefined up to a $k\pi$ addition. This way of speaking of functions has been I would say eradicated but in the domain of **complex function theory** where it is fundamntal in particular for logarithm function. Have you followed a lecture on the subject ?